# How to create a read-only property?

Tags: delphi

I am using a TMS object inspector at run time, but assume my question would be equally valid for Delphi at design time.

I want to have a property which can be set programically (at run time) or hard coded (at design time). It should be visible to the user as the information is useful to him and it should be changeable at run-time by the program but not by the user via the object inspector.

I tried

```
published property FileName : String read FFileName;
```

and the property is visible, but it is also changeable in the object inspector (and throws a read of address zer0 exception when changed)   :-(

Comment: You keep on assuming that the TMS control works the same way as Delphi's Object Inspector. Please stop doing that. It doesn't. This time, the difference is that the Object Inspector doesn't even *display* read-only properties, so this thing about "read of address 0" simply doesn't apply and seems to be a bug with TMS.

Comment: @Rob, There's a setting that you can toggle to make the Delphi object inspector display readonly properties *(or not)*. It's somewhere in the tools-> options dialog.

Comment: Quick workaround solution: Drop the TMS property inspector and use the JEDI one.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This looks like a perfectly valid and correct **read-only** property

```
published property FileName : String read FFileName;
```

if you add an extra property that public and thus only settable during runtime you're in business:

```
public property RuntimeFilename: string read FFileName write FFilename;
//note that two properties, one published and one public point to the same field.
```

However if you want to hack it and get rid of the exception in Design-time
change it to:

```
//Only writable during runtime.
private
  procedure SetFileName(Value: string);
published
  property FileName: string read FFileName write SetFileName;

....
procedure TMyClass.SetFileName(Value: string);
begin
  if csDesigning in Componentstate then {do nothing}
  else FFileName:= Value;
end;
```

**What I think might also be going on...**

**Disconnect between designtime and runtime code**
In order to change the runtime behaviour of the code you need **only** change the source code and remove the `write ...` part of the property.

This will **not** effect the design-time code though, for that you need to reinstall the component.
If you change the source code of a registered component and you keep the changes within the `private`, `protected` and/or `public` sections of the component you are usually OK.

However if you change the `published` part of a component and you do not reinstall that component you will have abnormal behaviour at startup.

This is because in **design-time** you are still working with the old/unchanged binary versions of the component. This version has **not had the `write` part removed** and allows you to change the underlying string `FFilename`.

Come **runtime** the init-code will read the form resource 1) and spots a value to be written to FFilename. However the procedure `SetFilename` is no longer available and therefore a access violation occurs during program startup.

1)  *(the data that was in the .dfm file and is now stored inside a dfm resource in your .exe)*

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way:

```
private
  procedure SetFileName(Value: string);
published
  property FileName: string read FFileName write SetFileName;

....
procedure TMyClass.SetFileName(Value: string);
begin
  FFileName := FFileName;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to reply. I have tried that but the user can change the value via the object inspector, which I do not want. The property has a white background, as do all others, and can be edited. I would prefer it to have  a grey background (like a fixed row on a string-grid) and the user must not be allowed to change its value. (If we can't see how to do this, I will make it private, but would rather have it published)

Comment: Yes, Mawg, the property can be edited. But after editing, does the control continue to display the new, edited value? It shouldn't, because the underlying field's value hasn't been changed. If the new value appears, then that's another bug in the TMS control; in the real Object Inspector, Ken's code would succeed in creating a property that's displayed at design time but which ignores attempts at editing it.

Comment: @Mawg: There's no way, AFAICT, to make a read-only property appear disabled. But the users should figure out pretty quickly that trying to change it does nothing; hitting enter or leaving the property reverts it back to the previous (read-only) value, as @Rob mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

This is clearly a bug in the TMS object inspector and you should file a bug report with TMS.

Comment: It could be by design.  Oh wait... except the crashing part. :-)